# Unregistered token error after sending one notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing this dramatic problem with my android app while using Firebase. 
1. My app receives token on the first launch
2. I am able to send notification from firebase console to the registered token
3. If I try to send a notification again with the console just after step 2. It shows me "unregistered token" after 2nd attempt onwards.

I have all necessary configuration already there in the manifest and google service.json file is also in place with the correct configuration. I believe things are correct because the app is able to receive notification once and the problem starts coming only after that.

Update 1:
If I uninstall app and reinstall it then also I am able to receive notification only once.

Those who wants to look at the code, this is how I am getting token:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    //Getting registration token
     refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    //Displaying token on logcat
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
     saveDeviceToken(refreshedToken);
}
```

This gets calls only first launch and after that, I haven't seen it getting called (which I think is expected behavior).

OnMessage received also gets called on first notification and then it never gets called off:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("FCM", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d("FCM", "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

Update 2 :
Tried to hit the HTTP api of FCM using the same server key and token and got following response:

```
   {
  "multicast_id": 6286279702096230688,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    }
  ]
}
```

Just to avoid cross questions here are few more details:

- Android studio  : v2.3.1
- Google play service version : 10.0.1
- Libraries included : core, database, storage, messaging - all is having same version as google play service 10.0.1

Update 3 : Firebase crash, database and storage is working in the same project (which shows that google service.json file is correct).

Please help me to get it fixed.

Comment: When testing, have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the app first?

Comment: Yes! I tried this. I also tried rebuilding caches, complete change of packages and json file as well.

Comment: I suggest you to **update google play services & firebase to the latest 10.2.4**. Firebase is still in its late beta stages and many of its functions break & gets fixed in updates for example, from Firebase 10.0.x to  10.2.x the change of username/photo was buggy & didn't appear in real time without a re-login. It's been fixed now after contacting Firebase a many times. Also **onMessageReceived()** is called when your app is running in the background. If your app is stopped then the notification is handled by default system notification.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here how I fixed out.

As pointed out by everyone that package name of .json file could be the main reason of this failure which got true here as well but with a twist.

I had downloaded the .json file from Firebase and was assuming that correct .json file was getting downloaded. Unfortunately due to some bug in Firebase on downloading the file, I was always getting the .json file of some of my other project (firebase app).
On investing the downloaded file, I figured it out and change the package name and keys manually on .json file.

I was suggest everyone to check the included .json file before trying anything else as that is the primary reason of this type of issue.

Comment: if you receive first notif so its not about package name so your answer is wrong too

Answer (score 1):

I remember facing the similar problem before. Here is what I did and its working smooth for me. Hope this helps,

PreferenceStore is a helper class to save, edit and delete shared preferences.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.i(TAG, "New FCM Token: " + token);

    setup_flag = PreferenceStore.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(), PrefKeys.IS_FIRST_FCM_TOKEN);
    if (!setup_flag) {
        // save token and boolean value in shared preferences for 
        // the first time you run the app after install
        PreferenceStore.saveString(getApplicationContext(), "FCM_TOKEN", token);
        PreferenceStore.saveBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "IS_FIRST_FCM_TOKEN", true);
    } else {
        // other time your app loads, update the token (like call the API endpoint).
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The registration token may change when:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

you can see the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#access_the_registration_token)

and you can read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors) also about fcm errors
this happens for debug mode only so you can call this method in your launcher activity this will accept the HTTPS certificate of Test/Development server, as the HTTPS certificate is invalid /not trusted
In release it will be okay.

```
private void RegisterFireBase()
        {

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {    
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
                Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId?.Token?.ToString(), instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));

            });


            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;



        }
```

Comment: this answer is wrong not worked out

Answer (score 0):

FCM is the opposite of GCM.

While using GCM classes, the TokenID is refreshed every now and then thats why it is also updated in the Database on the server.

While using FCM. FCM basic architecture works on unique TokenID, this is the reason that onTokenRefresh does not invoke multiple times. It only invokes once.

What you have to do is just save your **INITIALLY** generated TokenID and utilize it accordingly.

**P.S: In FCM token does not refresh not until and unless the app is Reinstalled.**

Comment: Just to inform you that I am saving token id at my database and when I send notification on the same it works for first notification and then after all subsequent notification it shows me above mentioned error.

Comment: its not about caching or storing token its about unregistring token when fcm unregistered your token it does not matter you save it or not